# Are "Tell me everything that might cause my code to explode" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Example here:

[Are there any caveats to swapping out DesignMode for LicenseManager.UsageMode in a WinForms UserControl constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11404420/102937)

OK, so my question *is* a bit rhetorical.  But is the linked post specific enough to avoid the "Not Constructive" gavel?

Answer (score 3):

That is an interesting one, it could go either way - you could end up with a bunch of little snippets of information all as separate answers, or you might get an experienced (commercial) control writer come along and give an excellent answer.

IMVHO there is merit in the question, but if the answers come in dribs and drabs then they may need to be aggregated into one CW answer. IOW, I'm advocating that we/you keep an eye on it and manage it, rather than closing it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a fair question, the hack is unintuitive but is very well known.  It is reasonable to ask what side-effects it may have, given that it is so impenetrable.  Not sure why he was happy with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a fair question to me.

From your title, I was expecting a crappy code review question, but this describes a specific technique and asks if there are issues with it. It's exactly the sort of question I've had many time while working with MS APIs, due to MSDN's frequent lack of any notes as to the expected usage scenarios for the class or function being documented.

Yeah, on the face of it it's a poll question, however it lacks the breadth that makes most polls so problematic. I wouldn't worry about it.